# Build Qt Designer for Windows

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using Windows 10 and I just want to change a little function on Qt designer 5.15.2 , is there a simple method to recompile the designer exe without much complications
I downloaded the sources and tried using cmake directly without success ,
Then I installed qt 6.2.2  and tried compiling designer.pro but got many errors
Any idea how to it faster ?

Comment: You have to build Qt itself. This is usually easy if you install the proper dependencies. I have built Qt on windows thousands of times. Although with that said I don't use Qt6.

Comment: The instructions and requirements are here: [https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git) I use ActiveStatePerl and ActiveStatePython.

Comment: Qt5 build requirements are here: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) which include Perl and Python.